# Slide div from under another div

Tags: jquery, css, html, slide

I have a `div` which contains products that you can add by pressing the `add` link. And when you press the `add` link, an info message fades in and after 4 seconds fades out.

This message fades in and out at the top of the `childbox-content` `div` which is not visible for the user if he scrolls down in the `div` and clicks one of the last `li`.

My question is, how can I make the `info` `div` slide under the "Test" header in stead? This header is always visible to the user.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/11/)

EDIT: by the way, I can't get the `info` `div` to appear in the jsFiddle after an add link is pressed. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your class on each link in the markup is `.hprlink` when you're looking for `hprlink`. Just remove the period. You use the period in a selector looking for a class, not when you're defining a class.

Second, try using JQuery [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideup/)to hide the `infoDiv`:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/13/)

Comment: Btw, a small problem when using your approach. It pushes the `div` down. How can I overlap it in stead? So the info message will be on top of the `div`.

Comment: @Quoter Just set the `infoDiv` to `position:absolute` and you can use the `top` and `left` properties to set it accordingly. Just make sure you realize doing so will take that div out of the flow of the  document and everything else will re-position as if it wasn't there. http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/17/

Comment: Nothing strange happened with the layout, worked perfectly thanks!

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/e62Wu/14/

Just move the infoDiv up into the header div

```
<div class="header">
    <h3>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span><span style="margin-left:5px;">test</span>
    </h3>
    <div id='infoDiv' class='alert alert-info alert-dismissable'>
    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
    just an information message.............
    </div>
</div>
```

I had to fix all your

```
  <a href="#" class="hprlink">add</a>
```

to make your fiddle work.  There shouldn't be a . before the class name

Comment: Ah yea of course, I did a find and replace all. My bad, thanks!